# Julia: Function Arguments – Type Specification of Arrays

Tags: arrays, types, arguments, julia

It seems like i missed something about multiple dispatch + parametric types:

Integer is an abstract supertype of all integer types, so the method `f(arg::Integer)` works as expected:

```
f(arg::Integer) = println("an integer")
# f(42) prints "an integer"
# f(UInt8(42)) prints "an integer"
```

But if i you try the same with an one-dimensional Array of Integers as an argument type, julia answers with an error message:

```
f(arg::Array{Integer, 1}) = println("an array with integers")
f(arg::Array{Signed, 1}) = println("an array with signed integers")
# f([1,2,3]) gives "no method matching f(::Array{Int64,1})..."
```

Any idea what is wrong here? – Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into parametric type invariance, that is the nice orange warning box in the manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Parametric-Composite-Types-1).

Citing the relevant part:

> Concrete Point types with different values of T are never subtypes of each other:

```
julia> Point{Float64} <: Point{Int64}
false

julia> Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}
false
```

> Warning
>
> This last point is very important: even though Float64 <: Real we DO NOT have Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}.

For your example, you would need:

```
f(arg::Array{<:Integer, 1}) = println("an array with integers")
# Alternatively f(arg::Array{T, 1}) where T <: Integer = println("an array with integers")
f(arg::Array{Signed, 1}) = println("an array with signed integers")
```

The first method is then a fall-back for general integer Arrays, and the second can be called with the specific type `Array{Signed, 1}`:

```
julia> f([1,2,3])
an array with integers

julia> f(Array{UInt8, 1}([1,2,3]))
an array with integers

julia> f(Array{Signed, 1}([1,2,3]))
an array with signed integers
```